# Formulario guarda datos de cajas de texto vacías

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo un formulario para que guarde los datos de entre 1 a 6 personas resulta que si dejo algunas cajas de texto en blanco me guarda el registro en de los 6 en blanco y quiere que si se ingresen dos, que solo se guarden los 2 ó 1 o los que se ingresen

```
<?php 
include ('control.php');
$boton= $_POST['boton'];
$idgrupo= $_POST['idgrupo'];
$carrera= $_POST['carrera'];
$periodo= $_POST['periodo'];
//------ 1
$boton1= $_POST['boton1'];
$ced_alum= $_POST['ced_alum'];
$nom= $_POST['nom'];
$ape= $_POST['ape'];
$turno= $_POST['turno'];
//------ 2
$boton2= $_POST['boton2'];
$ced_alum2= $_POST['ced_alum2'];
$nom2= $_POST['nom2'];
$ape2= $_POST['ape2'];
$turno2= $_POST['turno2'];
//------ 3
$boton3= $_POST['boton3'];
$ced_alum3= $_POST['ced_alum3'];
$nom3= $_POST['nom3'];
$ape3= $_POST['ape3'];
$turno3= $_POST['turno3'];
//------ 4
$boton4= $_POST['boton4'];
$ced_alum4= $_POST['ced_alum4'];
$nom4= $_POST['nom4'];
$ape4= $_POST['ape4'];
$turno4= $_POST['turno4'];
//------ 5
$boton5= $_POST['boton5'];
$ced_alum5= $_POST['ced_alum5'];
$nom5= $_POST['nom5'];
$ape5= $_POST['ape5'];
$turno5= $_POST['turno5'];
//------ 6
$boton6= $_POST['boton6'];
$ced_alum6= $_POST['ced_alum6'];
$nom6= $_POST['nom6'];
$ape6= $_POST['ape6'];
$turno6= $_POST['turno6'];


// Buscar alumno 1
if ($boton1=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom = $registro['nom'];
        $ape = $registro['ape'];
        $turno = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 1

// Buscar alumno 2
if ($boton2=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum2'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum2 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom2 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape2 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno2 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 2

// Buscar alumno 3
if ($boton3=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum3'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum3 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom3 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape3 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno3 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 3

// Buscar alumno 4
if ($boton4=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum4'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum4 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom4 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape4 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno4 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 4

// Buscar alumno 5
if ($boton5=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum5'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum5 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom5 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape5 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno5 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 5

// Buscar alumno 6
if ($boton6=="Buscar") {
    # code...
    $sql="Select * from alumno where ced_alum ='$ced_alum6'";
    $busqueda=mysql_query($sql);
    if($registro=mysql_fetch_array($busqueda)){
        $ced_alum6 = $registro['ced_alum'];
        $nom6 = $registro['nom'];
        $ape6 = $registro['ape'];
        $turno6 = $registro['turno'];

            }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Registro No existe en el Sistema')</script>";
        }
}
// Cierre Alumno 6
if ($boton=="Guardar") {

    $sql="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum', '$nom', '$ape', '$turno')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    $sql2="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum2', '$nom2', '$ape2', '$turno2')";
        mysql_query($sql2); 
    $sql3="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum3', '$nom3', '$ape3', '$turno3')";
        mysql_query($sql3); 
    $sql4="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum4', '$nom4', '$ape4', '$turno4')";
        mysql_query($sql4);     
    $sql5="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum5', '$nom5', '$ape5', '$turno5')";
        mysql_query($sql5); 
    $sql6="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum6', '$nom6', '$ape6', '$turno6')";
        mysql_query($sql6); 
        if (mysql_query($sql)) {
        echo "<script> alert ('Data Almacenda')</script>";
        echo "<script> window.location='registro_grupo.php'</script>";
        # code...
    } else {
        echo "<script> alert ('No Guardado')</script>";
        # code...
    }   
    }


//Botones Simples --------------------------------------------------------------------


if($boton=="Limpiar"){
        echo "<script>window.location='registro_grupo.php'</script>";   
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registro de grupos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">


<center><h1><font color="blue">Datos de Grupo</font></h1></center>

<table align="center" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0" border="0">

<tr>
<td align="right"><Strong>Grupo Nro:</Strong></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="idgrupo" required placeholder="N° que identificará al grupo" value="<?PHP echo $idgrupo; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right"><strong>Carrera:</strong></td>
<td><input type="text" name="carrera" value="<?php echo $carrera; ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td align="right"><strong>Periodo Academico:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="periodo" value="<?php echo $periodo; ?>"></td>
</tr>

</table>

<p><label><h1><font color="blue"><center>Integrantes:</center></font></h1></label></p>
<center>
<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton1" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom" value="<?PHP echo $nom; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape" value="<?PHP echo $ape; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno" value="<?PHP echo $turno; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum2" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum2; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton2" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom2" value="<?PHP echo $nom2; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape2" value="<?PHP echo $ape2; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno2" value="<?PHP echo $turno2; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum3" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum3; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton3" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom3" value="<?PHP echo $nom3; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape3" value="<?PHP echo $ape3; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno3" value="<?PHP echo $turno3; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum4" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum4; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton4" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom4" value="<?PHP echo $nom4; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape4" value="<?PHP echo $ape4; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno4" value="<?PHP echo $turno4; ?>">
</p>

<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum5" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum5; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton5" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom5" value="<?PHP echo $nom5; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape5" value="<?PHP echo $ape5; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno5" value="<?PHP echo $turno5; ?>">
</p>
<p>
<label>Cédula: </label><input type="text" name="ced_alum6" value="<?PHP echo $ced_alum6; ?>"><input type="submit" name="boton6" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
<label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nom6" value="<?PHP echo $nom6; ?>">
<label>Apellido: </label><input type="text" name="ape6" value="<?PHP echo $ape6; ?>">
<label>Turno: </label><input type="text" name="turno6" value="<?PHP echo $turno6; ?>">
</p>

</center>


<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="7" border="0">
    <tr>
<td><div align="right"><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary"></div></td>
<td><div align="right"><input type="submit" name="boton" value="Limpiar" class="btn btn-warning"></div></td>
<td><div align="right"><a href="http://localhost/sercom/menu3.php">Volver</a></div></td>
   </tr>
</table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: buff... demasiado codigo, demasiado texto...

tienes problemas conceptuales en tu codigo, por lo menos comprueba que las variables recogidas esten rellenas, no ¿?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma mas simple es validar si el dato esta o no vacio por ejemplo.

```
if(!empty($valor)){
 //Codigo para guardar
}
```

por otro lado te recomiento que trabajes ese script con arreglos.

Comment: Amigo gracias por tu aporte, me funciona, pero ahora me guarda 1 registro 2 veces, así duplicado, lo único distinto es la clave primaria en el mysql que no la tomo en cuenta y por eso en el registro la pongo como null

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de

// Cierre Alumno 6

```
if ($boton=="Guardar") {
  if(strlen($nom)>0){
    $sql="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum', '$nom', '$ape', '$turno')";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
    if(strlen($nom2)>0){
    $sql2="insert into grupo values (null, '$idgrupo', '$carrera', '$periodo', '$ced_alum2', '$nom2', '$ape2', '$turno2')";
        mysql_query($sql2);
    }

 ......
    } else {
        echo "<script> alert ('No Guardado')</script>";
        # code...
    }   
    }
```

Aun asi te recomiendo que leas sobre Modelo-Vista-Controlador para organizar tu codigo segun los nuevos standars